# Optimize time process from Table function

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I have a process that consists of obtaining a data set by scanning 5 variables `L`, `w`, `d`, `k`, and `l` using `Table`. The script follows,

```
sa = Table[
   If[k == l, 
    Sin[  w (((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L)  k - 10^(-6 + L) l )^2)^(
        1/2)) ]/((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k - 
          10^(-6 + L) l )^2)^2, 
    Cos[d] Sin[
       w (((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L)   k + 
              10^(-6 + L) l (Cos[d]))^2 + ((10^(-6 + L) l (Sin[
                 d])))^2 )^2)]/(((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L)   k + 
            10^(-6 + L) l (Cos[d]))^2 + ((10^(-6 + L) l (Sin[
               d])))^2 )^2)], {L, 0, 3}, {w, 10, 100, 0.1}, {d, 0, 
    2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/4}, {k, 1, 200}, {l, 1, 200}];
```

The time taken to complete this process was about 10 hours on an  Intel® Core™ i7-6500U (2.50 GHz) processor, 8GB Single Channel DDR3L 1600MHz (1x8GB) memory, and  NVIDIA GeForce 930M 4GB DDR3.  I wonder if it is possible to reduce the calculation time using `For` or `Do`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can speed up the calculation considerably by finding numeric solutions instead of exact ones. Moreover, it helps if you avoid branching `If` statement. If it is still sufficiently, look up `Compile`, which compiles the function in low level C for even faster execution. You can also evalute the elements of the table in parallel on multiple cores using `ParallelTable`.

Below is a demonstration of compiling:

```
test := Table[
   If[k == l, 
    Sin[w (((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k - 10^(-6 + L) l)^2)^(1/
           2))]/((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k - 
           10^(-6 + L) l)^2)^2, 
    Cos[d] Sin[
       w (((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k + 
               10^(-6 + L) l (Cos[d]))^2 + ((10^(-6 + L) l (Sin[
                  d])))^2)^2)]/(((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k + 
             10^(-6 + L) l (Cos[d]))^2 + ((10^(-6 + L) l (Sin[
                d])))^2)^2)], {L, 0, 3}, {w, 10, 100, 1}, {d, 0, 
    2 \[Pi], \[Pi]}, {k, 1, 10}, {l, 1, 10}];
f = Compile[{L, w, d, k, l}, 
   If[k == l, 
    Sin[w (((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k - 10^(-6 + L) l)^2)^(1/
           2))]/((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k - 
           10^(-6 + L) l)^2)^2, 
    Cos[d] Sin[
       w (((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k + 
               10^(-6 + L) l (Cos[d]))^2 + ((10^(-6 + L) l (Sin[
                  d])))^2)^2)]/(((10^(-8 + L))^2 + (10^(-6 + L) k + 
             10^(-6 + L) l (Cos[d]))^2 + ((10^(-6 + L) l (Sin[
                d])))^2)^2)]];
testN := Table[
   f[N@L, N@w, N@d, N@k, N@l], {L, 0, 3}, {w, 10, 100, 1}, {d, 0, 
    2 \[Pi], \[Pi]}, {k, 1, 10}, {l, 1, 10}];
```

Testing:

```
Timing[test] // First
Timing[testN] // First
testN == test
```

> ```
> 1.98438
>
> 0.296875
>
> True
> ```